# Inserting and centering figures inside of a cell in a table (NiceTabular environment, nicematrix package)

Tags: tables, floats, nicematrix

I am still learning about nicematrix package. In this case, I want insert figures inside a NiceTabular and if it is possible, they have vertical centering and be at the same level to the text of the cell.

I tried with NiceTabular and pNiceArray but I don't obtain elegant results. Or I should use another packages? Thanks for your attention!

I attach my code and a couple of images.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix} %Paquete bonito para tablas, matrices y arreglos
\usepackage{tikz} %Permite usar block (multicolumnas o multirenglones en este paquete)
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para utilizar comandos de tablas elegantes

\begin{table}
\centering
%\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=4pt, cell-space-bottom-limit=4pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{Wc{2cm}ll}
\toprule
\Block{2-3}{\smallskip \makecell{Área de\\Iconos} \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{barra_icn.png} } & & \\
 & &\\
\midrule
\Block{4-1}{Función} & & \\
&\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{nuevo.png}  Nuevo & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{abrir.png} Abrir \\
&\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{guardar_como.png}  Guardar como & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{guardar.png}  Guardar \\
& \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{borrar.png}  Borrar & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{deshacer.png}  Deshacer/Cancelar \\
& \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{rehacer.png}  Rehacer/Revisar & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ajustes.png}  Ajustes \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
```

What I obtain [image]

What I wish to obtain[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you have special reason to use `NiceTabular`?
- In this case I don't see any benefits to use it.
- With standard tabular and `\adjustimage` defined in the `adjustbox` package you can obtain the following table:

[image]

- for above result is sufficient to compile the following MWE only once:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo, % in real document remove "demo" option
            export]{adjustbox} % for vertical centering ofimages
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix} %Paquete bonito para tablas, matrices y arreglos
\usepackage{tikz} %Permite usar block (multicolumnas o multirenglones en este paquete)
            
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \adjustboxset{height=2cm, width=2cm, % adjust images size according to your needs
                  valign=c, margin=3pt}  
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}Wc{2cm} l l }
    \toprule
\makecell{Área de\\Iconos} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\adjustimage{width=8cm, height=1cm}{barra_icn}}\\
    \midrule
\multirow{17}{*}{Función}   
    & \adjustimage{}{nuevo}  Nuevo 
        & \adjustimage{}{abrir} Abrir \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \adjustimage{}{guardar_como}  Guardar como 
        & \adjustimage{}{guardar}  Guardar \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \adjustimage{}{borrar}  Borrar 
        & \adjustimage{}{deshacer}  Deshacer/Cancelar \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \adjustimage{}{rehacer}  Rehacer/Revisar 
        & \adjustimage{}{ajustes}  Ajustes \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**
Similar result you can obtain with se of the recent version of the `nicematrix` package, however with it you need to compile MWE twice:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix} %Paquete bonito para tablas, matrices y arreglos
%\usepackage{tikz} %Permite usar block (multicolumnas o multirenglones en este paquete)
            
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=2cm, width=2cm}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=3pt, cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt}
  
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}Wc{2cm} l l }
    \toprule
\makecell{Área de\\Iconos} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=1cm,
                                                                 valign=c]{barra_icn}}\\
    \midrule
\Block{4-1}{\textbf{Función}}   
    & \includegraphics[valign=c]{nuevo}  Nuevo
        & \includegraphics[valign=c]{abrir} Abrir \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \includegraphics[valign=c]{guardar_como}  Guardar como
        & \includegraphics[valign=c]{guardar}  Guardar \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \includegraphics[valign=c]{borrar}  Borrar
        & \includegraphics[valign=c]{deshacer}  Deshacer/Cancelar \\
    %\addlinespace
    & \includegraphics[valign=c]{rehacer}  Rehacer/Revisar
        & \includegraphics[valign=c]{ajustes}  Ajustes \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zarko!! Actually, I don't have a reason, just for fun, I started to use `nicematrix` because it helped me with a table and I liked it. Thanks for your help and your attention.